# Problema con consulta mysql y puntos contatenados

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que no me funciona y me da error

```
select sum(importe) 
from detalleboletas 
where fechapago='2019-02-20' and (estado='2' or estado='4') and cuentahija 
in (1.1.1.1.5.1,1.4.1,1.4.2,1003105)
```

Si hago la misma consulta, pero sin el separador de punto (.) me funciona.

```
select sum(importe) 
from detalleboletas 
where fechapago='2019-02-20' and (estado='2' or estado='4') and cuentahija 
in (111151,141142,1003105)
```

Ya me perdí si alguien puede guiarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: y el punto en esos valores es opcional? así estan almacenados en tu base de datos?

Comment: Lo que está sucediendo es que en el segundo caso (sin puntos) el valor es tomado como un número,  un entero. En cuanto al primer caso no tenemos un número tenemos un **String** por lo que para que sea interpretado como tal debemos encerrarlo entre comillas.

Comment: el problema es q los datos vienen con puntos, esos datos los obtengo con un GROUP_CONCAT(codigo) , como se hace para que el resultado de ahi salga con adicionales entre comillas simples?,   '1.1.1.1.5.1','1.4.1.1.4.2','1.0.0.3.1.0.5' Gracias

Comment: Encuentro que si pongo esto group_concat(concat(':',`codigo`,':') separator ',')  logro obtener :1.1.1.1.5.1:,:1.1.1.2.1:,:1.1.1.2.2:   Si reemplazo esos : por comilla simple da error la consulta.  Salvo que despues reemplaze los dos puntos con php y le ponga comillas?

Comment: probando probando , le agregue mas comillas simples,  group_concat(concat('''',`codigo`,'''') separator ',')  y ahi arroja.  lo que necesito, ahora hay que probar si realizar la suma!!!!!  ('1.1.1.1.5.1','1.1.1.2.1','1.1.1.2.2')

Answer (score 0):

creo que de esta forma funciona, tendria que concatenar valor por valor.

```
select sum(importe) from detalleboletas where fechapago='2019-02-20' and (estado='2' or estado='4') and cuentahija in ('1.1.1.1.5.1','1.4.1,1.4.2','1003105')
```

si alguien tiene mejor solucion, se lo agradezco .